# Pointing a subdomain to Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I've got a website hosted on firebase www.example.com.  I'd like to serve some functions in the same project from api.example.com.
Rewrites seem to only support directories and not subdomains though.  Has anyone been able to accomplish this?  Do I have to just use two different firebase projects?

Comment: Did you solved it? because I have the same  issue :(

Answer (score 3):

Rewrites won't handle domain names directly.  As you say, you can use a second project, and route calls to your API via your [custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) using [Firebase Hosting integration with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple sites on the [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/): Go to your project > hosting.

1. Create a new site on a subdomain of the domain you own i.e. api.example.com;
   (Confirm ownership for the domain etc.)
2. In your `firebase.json` update your `hosting` property to look something like this:

```
"hosting": [
  {
    "target": "mywebsite",
    "public": "website",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "mywebsite-api",
    "public": "apisite",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/hello-world",
        "function": "helloWorld",
        "region": "firebase-region3" // This is optional if you do not use regions for your functions
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

3. Put `index.html` and `404.html` files in the directory i.e. `apisite` to avoid errors. If you want to publish documentation of your API publicly, this could be a good place to put it.
4. Deploy with:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

now your function should be available on your subdomain i.e. https://api.example.com/hello-world

Comment: I see in the rewrite, you add the source as `/hello-world`, where did this come from?

Comment: @tapizquent, it's the route used when calling the function. i.e.: `www.api.mywebsite.com/hello-world`
Depending what url `mywebsite-api` is hosted on.